# Facing "fatal error" while saving picture taken in 2nd photo taking; 1st photo taking and picture saving work well

Tags: bitmap, camera, image-capture

I try to write an apps to take photo, save the photo at my desire directory with my desired name, bitmap the photo then place at the ImageReview.
I can work well in first photo taking, photo saving, photo bitmap and placing image at Image Review. While I try to redo this 2nd time, I still can launch the camera and take photo, but when saving the photo, i face issue with message "Unfortunately, XXXXXX has stopped". Need helps to resolve this. Thanks.

I suspect the command which cause this problem is as below because when i commented out this command line, I don't face this problem in 2nd time photo saving:
 cameraBox1.setImageBitmap(captureBmp);

Do I need to add anything to manage this?

Here are my coding:

```
  takeButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              image = getFile(MainActivity.this);
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image) );   
            startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);
           }
          });

public File getFile(Context context){  

      final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Image" );  
      if(!path.exists()){  
        path.mkdir(); 
      }
      String name;
      int n = 100000;
      int rand;
      rand = new Random().nextInt(n);
      name = "Image-" + rand + ".jpg";
      File fileimage = new File(path, name);

      return fileimage;  
    }  

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Image Captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       switch(requestCode){  
       case CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE:  

        try {  
          Bitmap captureBmp;
          captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(image) );

          ImageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
          String pathToImage = ImageUri.getPath();
          cameraBox1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraBox);

          cameraBox1.setImageBitmap(captureBmp);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
      cameraBox1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      cameraBox1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

      break;
      }
   } 
   else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

 }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
}
```

API That I use:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
```

Comment: What is the programming language and the lib used ?

Comment: java and and I have added in the APIs that i used